# Python csv.DictReader - how to reverse output?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, reverse

I'm trying to reverse the way a file is read. I am using DictReader because I want the contents in a Dictionary. I'd like to read the first line in the file and use that for the Keys, then parse the file in reverse (bottom to top) kind of like the linux "tac" command. Is there an easy way to do this? Below is my code to read the file into a dictionary and write it to a file...

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open(file_to_parse, 'r'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
for line in reader:
    # ...
```

This code works to process the file normally, however.. I need it to read the file from the end.

In other words, I'd like it to read the file:

```
fruit, vegetables, cars
orange, carrot, ford
apple, celery, chevy
grape, corn, chrysler
```

and be able to have it return:

```
{' cars': ' chrysler', ' vegetables': ' corn', 'fruit': 'grape'}
{' cars': ' chevy', ' vegetables': ' celery', 'fruit': 'apple'}
{' cars': ' ford', ' vegetables': ' carrot', 'fruit': 'orange'}
```

instead of:

```
{' cars': ' ford', ' vegetables': ' carrot', 'fruit': 'orange'}
{' cars': ' chevy', ' vegetables': ' celery', 'fruit': 'apple'}
{' cars': ' chrysler', ' vegetables': ' corn', 'fruit': 'grape'}
```

Comment: How many lines in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read to a list and reverse:

```
lines = [x for x in reader]
for line in lines[::-1]:
    print line

{' cars': ' chrysler', ' vegetables': ' corn', 'fruit': 'grape'}
{' cars': ' chevy', ' vegetables': ' celery', 'fruit': 'apple'}
{' cars': ' ford', ' vegetables': ' carrot', 'fruit': 'orange'}
```

Or as Martijn Pieters suggested:

```
for line in reversed(list(reader)):
```

Comment: `reversed(list(reader))` would do. There is certainly no need to use a list comprehension where `list()` would do.

Comment: You should not include the `list(reader)` call in your timings; create the list copy **once** (`lines = list(reader)`), then compare looping over `lines[::-1]` and `reversed(lines)`. Compare this with *varying sizes of `reader` output* too.

Comment: If you are going to compare performance of `reversed` vs. `listobject[::-1]`, then at least compare just that.

Comment: This worked great! Thanks!                                     lines = [x for x in reader]
for line in lines[::-1]:
    print line

Comment: @MartijnPieters,you mean time `lines[::-1]` and `reversed(r)` where `r` is `list(reader)`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: check.

Comment: Question.. Why did it not try and create the dictionary based on the items at the end of the list if that is how the file was read? dictreader seemed to know to use the first line anyway...

Comment: Is that because the dictionary had already been created (I assume) and we are just changing the list order after?

Comment: @celtic yes, we read the dicts into a list and revered the order of the list.

Comment: @celtic: the list of dictionaries is created *first*, then that list is reversed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, fair enough but why is `list(reader)` much slower than the comprehension?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: **both** have exhausted the `reader` iterable on the first call, `reader` returns **nothing**. You have empty lists here. You are timing `reversed()` vs reversing an empty list, and in that case the function call overhead is the most costly.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: if you want to test `list(iterable)` vs `[x for x in iterable]`, use a re-usable iterable object (e.g. a list object).

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to read the *whole* CSV file into memory; you can do so by calling `list()` on the reader object:

```
with open(file_to_parse, 'rb') as inf:
    reader = csv.DictReader(inf, skipinitialspace=True)
    rows = list(reader)

for row in reversed(rows):
```

Note that I used the file as a context manager here to ensure that the file is closed. You also want to open the file in binary mode (leave newline handling to the `csv` module). The rest of the configuration you passed to the `DictReader()` are the defaults, so I omitted them.

I set `skipinitialspace` to True, as judging from your sample input and output you do have spaces after your delimiters; the option removes these.

The `csv.DictReader()` object takes care of reading that first line as the keys.

Demo:

```
>>> import csv
>>> sample = '''\
... fruit, vegetables, cars
... orange, carrot, ford
... apple, celery, chevy
... grape, corn, chrysler
... '''.splitlines()
>>> reader = csv.DictReader(sample, skipinitialspace=True)
>>> rows = list(reader)
>>> for row in reversed(rows):
...     print row
... 
{'cars': 'chrysler', 'vegetables': 'corn', 'fruit': 'grape'}
{'cars': 'chevy', 'vegetables': 'celery', 'fruit': 'apple'}
{'cars': 'ford', 'vegetables': 'carrot', 'fruit': 'orange'}
```

Comment: actually faster using `lines[::-1]`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: that depends on the size of the list; `reversed()` doesn't create a new object, it merely uses the [`list.__reversed__()` iterator](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__reversed__). It is also more memory efficient this way.

Comment: You don't _have_ to read the whole file into memory. It's certainly easier, and probably faster for medium-sized files, but when you need to read the file in reverse it's not _that_ hard.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually *have* to read the whole file into memory.

A `csv.DictReader` doesn't actually require a file, just an iterable of strings.*

And you can read a text file in reverse order in average linear time with constant space with not *too* much overhead. It's not trivial, but it's not that hard:

```
def reverse_lines(*args, **kwargs):
    with open(*args, **kwargs) as f:
        buf = ''
        f.seek(0, io.SEEK_END)
        while f.tell():
            try:
                f.seek(-1024, io.SEEK_CUR)
            except OSError:
                bufsize = f.tell()
                f.seek(0, io.SEEK_SET)
                newbuf = f.read(bufsize)
                f.seek(0, io.SEEK_SET)
            else:
                newbuf = f.read(1024)
                f.seek(-1024, io.SEEK_CUR)
            buf = newbuf + buf
            lines = buf.split('\n')
            buf = lines.pop(0)
            yield from reversed(lines)
        yield buf
```

This isn't rigorously tested, and it strips off the newlines (which is fine for `csv.DictReader`, but not fine in general), and it's not optimized for unusual but possible edge cases (e.g., for really long lines, it will be quadratic), and it requires Python 3.3, and the file doesn't go away until you close/release the iterator (it probably should be a context manager so you can deal with that)—but if you really want this, I'm willing to bet you can find a recipe on ActiveState or distribution on PyPI with none of those problems.

Anyway, for a medium-sized file, I suspect it'd actually be faster, on almost any real-life filesystem, to read the whole thing into memory in forward order then iterate the list in reverse. But for a very large file (especially one you can't even fit into memory), this solution is obviously much better.

From a quick test (see http://pastebin.com/Nst6WFwV for code), on my computer, the basic breakdown is:

- Much slower for files <<1000 lines.
- About 10% slower from 1K-1M lines.
- Crossover around 30M lines.
- 50% faster at 500M lines.
- 1300% faster at 1.5G lines.
- Effectively infinitely faster at 2.5G lines (the list-reversing version throws my machine into swap hell, and I have to ssh in to kill the process and wait a couple minutes for it to recover…).

Of course the details will depend on a lot of facts about your computer. It's probably no coincidence that 500M 72-char lines of ASCII takes up close to half the physical RAM on my machine. But with a hard drive instead of an SSD you'd probably see more penalty for `reverse_lines` (since random seeks would be much slower compared to contiguous reads, and disk in general would be more important). And your platform's malloc and VM behavior, and even locality issues (parsing a line almost immediately after reading it instead of after it's been swapped out and back in…) might make a difference. And so on.

Anyway, the lesson is, if you're not expecting at least 10s of millions of lines (or maybe a bit less on a very resource-constrained machine), don't even think about this; just keep it simple.

---

<sub>*  As Martijn Pieters points out in the comments, if you're not using explicit `fieldnames`, `DictReader` requires an iterable of strings *where the first line is the header*. But you can fix that by reading the first line separately with a `csv.reader` and passing it as the `fieldnames`, or even by `itertools.chain`-ing all the first line from a forward read before all but the last lines of the backward read.</sub>

Comment: This does require reading the header separately, but that's hardly a problem, with a separate `csv.reader()` object reading just the first row.